# How to keep mat-horizontal-stepper to center of page

Tags: css, angular, angular6, angular-material-6, mat-stepper

[image]I am using Angular 6 mat-horizontal-stepper. I want to give some specific width to it and want to keep it in center of page.
For mat-horizontal-content-container  i am able to keep it in center

```
.mat-horizontal-content-container 
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
```

But how to keep the header to center of page.I am trying this but it is not working.

```
.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container 
    width: fit-content !important;
    align-items: center;
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Hi, did you get this working?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to also add: `margin: 0 auto`.

```
.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks @Unacorn. I used ngdeep So it is                                            
 ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

In your component.html:

```
<div class="stepperContainer">
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
   your stepper content will go here
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

In your component.css :

```
.stepperContainer{
width: fit-content;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will align the stepper to the center.

Answer (score -1):

Try with deep

```
  /deep/.mat-horizontal-content-container {
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

As deep will be deprecate soon alternative approach to write your style in global css file like in style.css

Comment: mat-horizontal-content-container is working fine as you can see in image. I want mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container to be align in center.@Vaibhav Phutane